# How to set a value to session variable without passing to php file

Tags: javascript, php, session

I've a problem with php code. I want to create a session in user side. But in that server their is no Apache or any other server. How can i create a session in that type static sites. I want to create session to maintain the user data to access from that site to my site. Like cross domaining data transfer.

I was used the Javascript code to maintain the session variable in client side but it is created in server. I want to create in client side. Please help....

Code like... Client side (Domain1.com)

```
 window.onload =  visitor(visitorid, myip, agent, company);
```

Code like... Sever side js file (Domain2.com)

```
var baseUrl = "../chat/";  

function visitor(visitor, ip, agent, company) {
    alert(company);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json', 
        url: baseUrl+"visitor.php?action=visitordetails",
        data: { 'visitor': visitor, 'agent': agent, 'ipadd': ip, 'company': company},
        success : function(data) { 
            alert('success' +data);
        }
    });
}
```

Server side PHP file

```
session_start();

if ($_GET['action'] == 'visitordetails') {
    # code...
    passtodb();
}

function passtodb()
{
    # code...
    if(isset($_POST['visitor']))
    {
      $visitor = $_SESSION['username'] =$_POST['visitor'];


}else{
    $visitor = $_SESSION['username'] = "Unknown_Guest";
}


}
```

I want to create a session on client side. how can i create please help me...

Comment: you can use HTML5 sessionstorage to uniquely identify a user computer

Comment: is it work properly??

Comment: I used the HTML5 sessnionstorage for this problem but i didn't get any solution... If you know just give a brief description about this

Comment: Sorry i didn't find the solution for this problem... Please guys i was stucked here